# how to loop through array (array of objects) starting at a specific index to the last and alter properties in the object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
let library = []; //this stores each object
```

Each object has a property called' id' where a number is stored, this represents the index of the object in the library array. Basically when an object is deleted from the library I want to get all the objects in the array that come after the deleted object and minus 1 from the id property.

```
function updateId(index) {
  for (let i = index; i <= library.length; i++) {
    library[i].id - 1;
  }
}
```

So far I have this function where the argument index is the position in the array where the object was deleted. I am getting a reference error with that last line of code

Comment: `for (let i = index; i < library.length; i++) {`  firsts array's index is **ZERO**

Comment: `library[i].id - 1` doesn't do anything on its own. I think you want `library[i].id -= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `i <= library.length` try `i < library.length`.

Currently that line is saying "continue this `for` loop so long as `i` is less than or equal to the length" ... but remember, `i` (ie. indices) are zero-based, while lengths aren't.  This means that you'll actually loop *past* where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Note this is just one of many ways to solve this!
You're almost there. There are a few things that your code needs:

- to have access to the 'library' inside of your function, you should pass it into the function. Functions should only operate on variables that they received as arguments.
- your for loop, should go on if i is SMALLER THAN not SMALLER EQUAL to the length
- if you're changing the 'library' in a function, you need to return it, and overwrite the original.

```js
function updateId(library, startingAtIndex) {
      for (let i = startingAtIndex; i < library.length; i++) {
        library[i].id -= 1;
      }
      return library
 }
 
things = [{name:'a', id:1},{name:'c', id:3},{name:'d', id:4}]
things = updateId(things, 1)
console.log(things)
```